# Bootstrap grid distorted

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" style="height:100px; background-color:#000000; padding:3px; border:2px solid grey; color:#ffffff">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="height:300px; background-color:#FFA444; padding:3px; border:2px solid grey;color:#ffffff">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="height:150px; background-color:#000000; padding:3px; border:2px solid grey;color:#ffffff">3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="height:40px; background-color:#FFA444; padding:3px; border:2px solid grey;color:#ffffff">4</div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="height:120px; background-color:#000000; padding:3px; border:2px solid grey;color:#ffffff">5</div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="height:130px; background-color:#FFA444; padding:3px; border:2px solid grey;color:#ffffff">6</div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="height:190px; background-color:#000000; padding:3px; border:2px solid grey;color:#ffffff">7</div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="height:121px; background-color:#FFA444; padding:3px; border:2px solid grey;color:#ffffff">8</div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="height:30px; background-color:#000000; padding:3px; border:2px solid grey;color:#ffffff">9</div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="height:90px; background-color:#FFA444; padding:3px; border:2px solid grey;color:#ffffff">10</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Im trying to make a grid that looks like a table, the div class='col-md-3' is dynamically generated.

It should look like a table which each row has only 4 columns. Because of the uneven heights, the image would stack together not looking like a table.

Is there a problem with the code? Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hNPs.png

Comment: you need to add more rows. as each of your columns is 3 wide, each row should contain only 4 of your columns.

Comment: Extending on what @2pha commented: If you look at the Bootstrap documentation, rows are based on a *12 column* grid system. Once you read 12 columns (such as 4 `col-md-3` divs), you need to close your div for "row" and start a new row.

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423892/bootstrap-gap-between-columns-on-mobile-display/30425750#30425750

Answer (score 2):

In bootstrap total number of columns are 12 in a row,only 4 col-md-3 can be placed in one row

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" style="height:100px; background-color:#000000; padding:3px; border:2px solid grey; color:#ffffff">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="height:300px; background-color:#FFA444; padding:3px; border:2px solid grey;color:#ffffff">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="height:150px; background-color:#000000; padding:3px; border:2px solid grey;color:#ffffff">3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="height:40px; background-color:#FFA444; padding:3px; border:2px solid grey;color:#ffffff">4</div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3" style="height:120px; background-color:#000000; padding:3px; border:2px solid grey;color:#ffffff">5</div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="height:130px; background-color:#FFA444; padding:3px; border:2px solid grey;color:#ffffff">6</div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="height:190px; background-color:#000000; padding:3px; border:2px solid grey;color:#ffffff">7</div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="height:121px; background-color:#FFA444; padding:3px; border:2px solid grey;color:#ffffff">8</div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if i want it to change when screensize is different?

for example <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-6"></div>

Comment: If you are showing data like table one record having 4 columns.then you don't need to change col-md-3 to col-lg-6. Add col-lg-3 for table as columns will remain same.

Comment: Also it depend upon on your design what number of columns you want to show on large medium and small resolution

Comment: i want it to display as 4 columns for large screen col-lg-3 and 2 columns for medium screens col-md-6, if so how do i position the <row></row> tag so that it wont be distorted?

Comment: <row></row> will not effect the design

Answer (score 2):

Because of the different column sizes, it happens so. This can be fixed by:

```
<div class="row" style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;">
    ...
</div>
```