# Bootstrap: Gap between columns on mobile display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I am doing a website using bootstrap 3.0 which I want the HTML and CSS to be seen neatly on a desktop, tablet and mobile.

A problem that I am having is that when you view the site on a mobile display the column are stacked (in which I am not criticizing as this stops scrolling as much as possible). However, I would like a little gap between the columns (even 1-2px).

The code so far

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
        <div class="Columns">
        ..content 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-4">
        <div class="Columns">
        ..content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

An image to show what this is doing and to display the stack columns

[image]

How could I achieve a little gap between the columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a custom class `.column-margin` to set the margin between the rows/columns.

```css
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .column-margin {
    margin: 2px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
    <div class="Columns column-margin">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-4">
    <div class="Columns">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Codeply**](http://www.codeply.com/go/whfN0JcgTK)

Answer (score 4):

Give a margin for the `col-xs-12` so all blocks will have bottom margin in mobile devices.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-xs-12 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get even spacing and column size I would do the following: (Note: change col-md-* to col-sm-* or col-xs-* as you like )

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 well">
            Some Content..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 well">
            Some Second Content..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 well">
            Some Second Content..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 well">
            Some Second Content..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 well">
            Some Second Content..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 well">
            Some Second Content..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 well">
            Some Second Content..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 well">
            Some Second Content..
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```